# normalising weibull distribution for a given data plotted in histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, weibull

I am trying to replicate this graph
    https://wind-data.ch/tools/weibull.php

The code I worked on, is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import dweibull
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

frequency =     [2.75,7.80,11.64,13.79,14.20,13.15,
11.14,8.72,6.34,4.30,2.73,1.62,0.91,0.48,
0.24,0.11,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.00]
k = 2.00
lambd =6.00
mu = 0
dist = dweibull(k,mu,lambd)
x = np.linspace(-20,20, 1000)

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.distplot(frequency, fit=stats.dist.pdf(x), kde=False)
sns.show()
```

I think I might had some logical error,
need help in correcting it (I am totally new to this stuff)

Initially, I tried matplotlib as:

```
plt.plot(x, 210 * dist.pdf(x),label=r'$k=%.1f,\ \ lambd=%i$' % (k,   lambd))
plt.xlim(0, 21)
plt.ylim(0, 15.0)
plt.hist(frequency,bins ='auto')
plt.show()
```

(instead of last three lines in prior code, didn't worked out)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure iiuc, but this would be my first approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def wd(x, k, A):
    return k/A*(x/A)**(k-1) * np.exp(-(x/A)**k)

frequency = [2.75, 7.80, 11.64, 13.79, 14.20, 13.15, 11.14, 8.72, 6.34, 4.30, 2.73, 1.62, 0.91, 0.48, 0.24, 0.11, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00]
k = 2.00
lambd = 6.00

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.step(range(len(frequency)), frequency, where='post')
plt.plot(wd(np.arange(len(frequency)), k, lambd)*100)
```

creates

[image]

Comment: sir, why didnt you used the weibull function in the library given

Comment: Because you only have the binned histogram values stored in `frequency`, not the (hopefully) weibull distributed original data. IIUC, the distribution functions in `scipy.stats` calculate a `pdf` from the raw data - otherwise these functions wouldn't have much left to do... That said, IMO `dweibull` would have been the wrong one anyway, as you do not have the double weibull case.